# nameerror : name 'bot' is not defined

Tags: python, telegram-bot, replit, py-telegram-bot-api

i am trying to create a telegram bot and its having issues

```
import os
import telebot

my_secret = os.environ['Example']

@bot.message_handler(command=['Greet'])
def greet(message):
  bot.reply_to(message, "Hey! Hows it going?")

bot.polling()
```

Comment: You have not declared or imported a variable named `bot`.  So yeah, it doesn't exist.  Why are you trying to use a variable that does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error you haven't defined `bot` before using that variable.
If you check the offical docs of pyTelegramBotAPI, even the example shows how to start by defining `bot` (https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/):

````
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")```
````